# Has anyone defined a spline function (i.e. defineFuction) in PMML?

Tags: predictive-modeling, algorithms, regression

Has anyone defined a spline function (i.e. defineFuction) in PMML?

There are quite a few parameters that need to be defined, with a fairly lengthy math. For example, for a predictor with a simple 3-knot restrictive cubic spline, I have seven parameters (including two coefficients, three knots, one reference point and one predictor name). The math includes a bit of exponential, max statements, etc.

For that matter, is there a library of functions other than those described on the PMML website documentation? It seems like it would be helpful to have a library of descriptions for even relatively simple functions like polynomials.